# react-use-gesture + spring - exclude nested elements from gesture recognition

Tags: react-spring

I've got [the following component](https://gist.github.com/daino3/c54d23b5b79d78e1e42baec40c6ba3e8) that wraps other components and enables swipe navigation using react-use-gestures and react-spring. It works swell.

You call it like so:

```
<AnimatedSwipeNavigation onSwipeLeft={navigateRight} onSwipeRight={navigateLeft}>
    <SomeOtherComponent>
</AnimatedSwipeNavigation>
```

However, I'd like to exclude nested components inside of `<SomeOtherComponent>` from gesture recognition (drag-n-drop elements).

[Visually, here's what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Rb6.jpg)

Thoughts? I'm not seeing much discussion in their issues about this.

Comment: Event from inner boxes gets bubbled up and we need to stop their propagation to parent box. See https://github.com/react-spring/react-use-gesture/blob/master/src/recognizers/DragRecognizer.ts#L57 and add appropriate handlers to inner boxes.

Comment: How did you address this?